# On isoclinism classes of finite p-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

With reference to
*James, Rodney*, [**The groups of order (p^6) ((p) an odd prime).**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2006106), Math. Comput. 34, 613-637 (1980). [ZBL0428.20013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0428.20013)., My question is can we get isoclinism class $\phi_2$ for a finite p-group of order $p^n$ ? Here, notation $ \phi_s(m_1,m_2...m_r)x_t $ denotes isoclinic class $\phi_2$ of type $(m_1,m_2...m_r)$ and $x_t$ denotes the genus of the group (defined in the article I have mentioned).